# How to do 2 summarize operation in one Kusto query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am stuck with a Kusto query.
This is what I want to do - I would like to show day wise sales amount with the previous month's sales amount on the same day.

```
datatable(DateStamp:datetime, OrderId:string, SalesAmount:int) 
[
   "02-01-2019", "I01", 100,
   "02-01-2019", "I02", 200,
   "02-02-2019", "I03", 250,
   "02-02-2019", "I04", 150,
   "02-03-2019", "I13", 110,
   "01-01-2019", "I10", 20,
   "01-02-2019", "I11", 50,
   "01-02-2019", "I12", 30,
]
| extend SalesDate = format_datetime(DateStamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
| summarize AmountOfSales = sum(SalesAmount) by SalesDate
```

This is what I see.

[image]

And, instead this is what I want to show as result --

[image]

I couldn't figure out how to add multiple summarize operator in one query.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
datatable(DateStamp:datetime, OrderId:string, SalesAmount:int) 
[
   "02-01-2019", "I01", 100,
   "02-01-2019", "I02", 200,
   "02-02-2019", "I03", 250,
   "02-02-2019", "I04", 150,
   "02-03-2019", "I13", 110,
   "01-01-2019", "I10", 20,
   "01-02-2019", "I11", 50,
   "01-02-2019", "I12", 30,
]
| summarize AmountOfSales = sum(SalesAmount) by bin(DateStamp, 1d)
| as hint.materialized = true T
| extend prev_month = datetime_add("Month", -1, DateStamp)
| join kind=leftouter T on $left.prev_month == $right.DateStamp
| project SalesDate = format_datetime(DateStamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), AmountOfSales, AmountOfSalesPrevMonth = coalesce(AmountOfSales1, 0)
```

| SalesDate | AmountOfSales | AmountOfSalesPrevMonth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2019 | 20 | 0 |
| 01/02/2019 | 80 | 0 |
| 02/01/2019 | 300 | 20 |
| 02/02/2019 | 400 | 80 |
| 02/03/2019 | 110 | 0 |